# How to use list value outside multi.exec() in Redis?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, redis, node-redis

I am using node_redis. I want to retrieve all value of list, save them in an array and use.
I am doing this:

```
var redis = require('redis');
var client = redis.createClient();
var coordiante = [];
multi = client.multi();

multi.exec(function(err, res) {
client.lrange('S4' , 0 ,5 ,function(err, len){
     len.forEach(function (index,item) {
        coordiante[item] = index;
  });
});
});
 console.log(coordiante);
```

But it gives an empty array. How to use variable coordinate outside multi.exec?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you are getting a proper response in multi.exec function by doing console.log  (res)